# Summarizing expense by customer number in Java

Tags: java

I want to code the following in Java.
I have the following customer file.

```
Name      acct spending
BigGuy     a1   30
BigGuy     a2   40
smallGuy   a1   300
smallGuy   a2   400
smallGuy   a3   400
AMR        a1   300
AMR        a2   400
```

I need to read the above file and calculate the total for each customer to produce the following.

```
BigGuy     70
SmallGuy 1100
AMR       700
```

Comment: Let  us know what you have done so far so that we can help you further.

Comment: The customer file... Is it a .txt file? And also... you should post your own attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: *I want to code the following in Java.* Great! How can we help?

Answer (score 0):

```
F  = open('spendFile.txt', "r")
arr = [];
for c in F.readlines()[0].split(): #this turns the file into a string and creates a list of each word 
    arr.append(c)
people = []
amount = []
for i in range(0,len(arr)/3):
    name = arr[i*3]
    a = arr[i*3+2]
    if(name not in people):
        people.append(name)
        amount.append(int(a))
    else:
        index = people.index(name)
        old = amount[index]
        new = old+int(a)
        amount[index] = new

for i in range(0,len(people)):
    print(people[i]+" "+str(amount[i]))
```

I put the string you mentioned early in your post into a text file called 'spendFile.txt'. This then reads this and places the string into an array where each entry is a single word. I then iterate over this and grab the name with the corresponding amount. I check these values against the current list of people and amounts and finally print the total amount corresponding with each name. Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:**
I did not notice that your original file had the first line of 'Name acct spending' and my program does not account for that. So you'll have to get rid of this line when testing and then programmatically throw it out when actually implementing this.